# Common Lisp: Why does delete-if if differ so much from remove-if combined with setf?

Tags: common-lisp

I was trying to perform a destructive operation on collection and noticed that delete-if was giving me surprising results in SBCL and GNU CLISP.

Combining setf with remove-if works as expected, but I can not understand why delete-if does not modify the list.

This is my code

```
(format t "trying weird delete-if problem~%")

(defun data ()
  (loop for x from 1 to 9 by 2 collect (cons x (1+ x))))

(defparameter *c1* (data))
(defparameter *c2* (data))

(format t "*c1* is now ~A~%" *c1*)
(format t "*c2* is now ~A~%" *c2*)

(delete-if
 (lambda (x)
   (progn
     (format t "trying to compare ~A ~A~%" x (equal x (cons 1 2)))
     (equal x (cons 1 2))))
 *c1*)

(format t "now trying remove-if~%")

(setf *c2* (remove-if
            (lambda (x)
              (progn
                (format t "trying to compare ~A ~A~%" x (equal x (cons 1 2)))
                (equal x (cons 1 2))))
            *c2*))

(format t "*c1* is now ~A~%" *c1*)
(format t "*c2* is now ~A~%" *c2*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `delete-if`, you must still assign the return value back to the variable which held the original list. This is because the destructive deletion can change the identity of the list.

A list's identity is its first cons cell, if the list is nonempty; or else its identity is the symbol `nil` if it is empty. If the destructive remove operation produces a list which is `nil` (when the previous list was not `nil`) or produces a list which has a different cons cell at the front, then the identity has changed. In this case, the new identity must be assigned back into the place which holds the list.

Destructive manipulation of a list doesn't mean that we don't have to assign anything to the variable due to lists having reference semantics.  Because Lisp lists are unencapsulated references to cells, or else to `nil`, when we work with a list destructively, we must regard the place where the list is stored as being part of the working definition of the list. A destructive list is not simply a reference to the first cell of a list or else `nil`, but a destructive list is the **place** which holds such a reference or else `nil`.

When treating a list destructively, you almost always want there to just be one place. It's part of the list; a destructive list should usually not exist in two places.

We can make ourselves a `delete-if-place` macro for deleting from a place which holds a sequence, similarly to how `push` and `pop` work with a place.

The easiest way to do this is to use `define-modify-macro`; unfortunately that macro wants to work with filtering functions that take the value of the place as the leftmost argument, whereas `delete-if` takes that as the second argument. We can write a wrapper function `alt-delete-if` which reverses the two arguments:

```
(defun alt-delete-if (pred seq &rest args)
  (apply #'delete-if seq pred args))
```

With `alt-delete-if` we say `(alt-delete-if list predicate ...)` rather than `(delete-if predicate list ...)`.

Then we can:

```
(define-modify-macro delete-if-place (&rest args) alt-delete-if)
```

Now we can do:

```
[1]> (defvar l (list 1 2 3 4 5 6))
L
[2]> (delete-if-place l #'oddp)
(2 4 6)
```

The place is updated with the new list:

```
[3]> l
(2 4 6)
```

I.e. `(delete-if-place place pred)` performs `(setf place (alt-delete-if pred place))`, except that `place` is evaluated only once.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering why it worked on longer lists and stopped working when the list got shorter.